# Error coming while deploying carbon application of WSO2 MI on Docker Container

Tags: docker, api, docker-compose, deployment, wso2

I am deploying carbon application (car file) of a service I made on docker. When I checked the logs after running command 'docker-compose up -d'. I am getting an error.

The error is below:

```
 Error while deploying carbon application /home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/OBDCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car org.wso2.micro.core.util.CarbonException: Error while extracting Carbon Application : OBDCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car

/home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/OBDCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car (Permission denied)
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are copying the Capps while building the Docker image. In your Dockerfile when copying the capps copy them like below, changing the owner of the files.

```
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 capps ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
```